# файл .lib не является приложением win32. visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Всем привет. Я скачал на Github проект на C++ и CMake.
Использую visual studio 2019.
Нажал открыть локальную папку, выбрал папку где находится файл CMakeLists.txt, проект открылся нормально.
Но при запуске выдает такую ошибку - файл .lib не является приложением win32.
Прикреплю скриншот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить. Раньше с C++ и CMake дела не имел.

Comment: Судя по логу сборки, в проекте присутствует несколько целей, среди которых есть как статические библиотеки, таки исполняемые файлы. Вероятно, вам надо в настройках запуска проекта выбрать правильную цель: исполняемый файл, а не статическую библиотеку.

Comment: @maestro, Настройки запуска это имеется ввиду тут? [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XQ8M.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XQ8M.png) Тогда да, я уже выбрал там нужный исполняемый файл.

Comment: @Ant0hin, можно редактировать свой вопрос, чтобы добавить уточнения. То, что вы выбрали - точно не то, что нужно. Я не знаю, как это делается в студии (очень давно с ней не работал), и вообще можно ли это сделать для проектов, импортированных из CMake, но вообще вы же можете напрямую из проводника запустить файл `console_solver.exe`

Comment: @maestro Да в папке проекта появилась папка out\build\x64-Debug - там есть файл console_solver.exe и он запускается и вся программа вроде как работает нормально. Но я то хочу запустить отладку и посмотреть как это работает в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Если в проекте есть project Solution - запускай Visual Studio'ю через этот файл (Project Solution содержит в себе нужные опции для компилирования) или же скомпилируй через cmake.

Comment: project Solution - такого файла нет. Я могу только открыть локальную папку где находится файл CMakeLists.txt, только тогда проект открылся.